# How to display a list of items inside a listview

Tags: android, listview

I am working on a UI which looks like below image
[image: Listview with subitem]
The approach I'm using right now is by creating a Listview that have another listview inside it to display the sub-items. 
I've read somewhere else that putting a listview inside a listview is a bad practice which could cause a major UI bug. The bug I'm experiencing right now is when the sub List Item is updated, my main outer ListView's height is not updating. For example if I delete one of my sub List item, my outer ListView will show some extra white-space at the end of it.
One of the solution that came to me is by using LinearLayout to display the subListItem but then how can I filter those LinearLayout? Any recommendation is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: I think first you'll have your Parent ListView then create a customized list then inside your customized list add another ListView so this is the hierarchy

ListView - >Customize List -> ListView

Comment: @G.Dator sorry, but what did you mean about Customize List? can you please add some details?

Comment: Customize list is the one with "Filter by days" in your image. But you can try Expandable listview too.

Comment: @G.Dator : I've done as what you suggest me before, I think that ExpandableListView is a better approach but how do you put the filter inside the ExpandableListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ExpandableListView` instead of simple `ListViews` . Its very easy to use . Please see the a sample code here:

https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: how to put the filter layout on those ExpandableListView?

Comment: in getGroupView of the adapter "ExpandableListAdapter" method you can put the main category layout . for example: FOOD and in getChildView you can put the subcategories layout Example: Indian, Chinese etc.

Let me know if its still not clear or i misunderstood

Comment: Thanks for the idea